# how to escape every character up to a point?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

**Situation :**

I want a variable to contain a command so I can execute it doing :

```
%command%
```

**Tries :**

```
set command=echo File used by cleaning executable ^>^> dummyfile
%command%
```

This works, however I have to do specific editing for each command... 
isn't there something that will take all after the = symbol as quote?

```
set command="echo File used by cleaning executable >> dummyfile"
%command%
```

then command is not recognised because of the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your idea with the quoting was not that bad:

```
set "command=echo File used by cleaning executable >> dummyfile"
```